# Having trouble generalizing a data cleaning solution to a function in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr, data-cleaning

I have a question about generalizing some code into a function in R. Below is the code I want to generalize:

```
#file name information 
years <-c("_1999.XPT","_2003.XPT","_2005.XPT","_2007.XPT","_2009.XPT","_2011.XPT","_2013.XPT","_2015.XPT")

  #create initial frame 
  assign("diabetes", get(paste0("diabetes",years[1])))

  #binding rest of frames 
  for(i in 2:length(years))
    {
      update_frame <- bind_rows(get("diabetes"),get(paste0("diabetes",years[i])))
      assign("diabetes", update_frame) 
    }
```

The basic idea is that I want to do a vertical join (bind_rows) of multiple year files into a single dataframe.

My attempted solution to this looks something like this:

```
big_bind <- function(name) 
{
  #create initial frame 
  assign(name, get(paste0(name,years[1])))

  #binding rest of frames 
  for(i in 2:length(years))
    {
      update_frame <- bind_rows(get(name),get(paste0(name,years[i])))
      assign(name, update_frame) 
    }

}

big_bind("diabetes")
```

The solution above doesn't work, which leaves me stumped because it works if I swap out the name variable for "diabetes". To be a little more specific, the code runs without errors, but doesn't do anything. I think it has something to do with how R defines variables for functions. Anybody see what I'm missing or has a solution?